# How to convert image values in float * to the format cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM could process

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got the gray scale values from 2 cameras, and they are stored in 2 separate float * (Values are in range(0, 1)).

After searching on the Internet, I fount that function 'cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM' could generate depth according to 'left' and 'right' views. My question is how to convert these 2 float * images to the format cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM could process, like IplImage or sth else.

I found that the first 2 parameters for cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM are in CvArr *.

Thanks

Comment: Multiply by 255 and make it "unsigned char"?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500423/opencv-gives-exception-with-cvfindstereocorrespondencebm

Comment: You should use opencv c++ api. Easier.